# Inferences from $H_A\simeq H_{A'}$ for $\mathbf{Grp}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, proof-explanation

From [pp.104-105](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf):

[image]

(1) [Second bullet point] How do we know that $H_A(\mathbb Z)=\{\text{group homomorphisms } \mathbb Z\to A\}$ is the underlying set of $A$? I can't even imagine why this could be true. $A$ was chosen to be an arbitrary group, and the set $H_A(\mathbb Z)$ is constructed using $A$.

(2) [Third bullet point] I think the result they are referring to is the fact that there is a bijection $$\{\text{group homomorphisms } \mathbb Z_p\to G\}\leftrightarrow\{\text{elements of } G \text{ of order }1 \text{ or } p\}$$
(this is not quite Example 4.1.5, but I used this fact to prove what is claimed in that example). 
This result should imply that for any $p$, $A$ and $A'$ have the same number of elements of order dividing $p$. Why does it follow that they have the same number of elements of order $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) notice that every homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ is completely determined by its image $\phi(1)$.

For (2), in example 4.1.5 they define $U_p:\textbf{Grp}\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$ that maps $G$ to the set of elements of order 1 or of prime order in $G$ and in exercise 4.1.28 it is proven that $U_p\simeq Hom(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},-)$, so what is said follows right away (since the number of elements of order p is equal to $|U_p(G)|-1$).

Comment: I'm not sure why this should establish what is claimed. This proves that there is a bijection between the homomorphisms $\mathbb Z\to A$ and $A$, but I don't see why $A$ has to be equal to this set of homomorphisms on the level of sets.

Comment: Precisely define $f:Hom(\mathbb{Z},A)\rightarrow A$ that maps $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ to $\phi(1)$. $f$ is bijective since $\phi_1(1)=\phi_2(1)$ implies that $\phi_1=phi_2$ and is surjective since for all $a\in A$ you can define $\phi_a:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ by $\phi_a(1)=1$.

Comment: @user634426 Let $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{Z},A)$ denote the set of group homomorphisms $\Bbb{Z}\to A$. Then $A$ is not equal to $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{Z},A)$, but there is a bijection between them. Also since there is a bijection between $A$ and $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{Z},A)$, it follows that $A$ and $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{Z},A)$ are isomorphic objects in the category of sets.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard So Leinster means that the underlying set of $A$ is isomorphic to $H_A(\mathbb Z)$, not equal to. Despite the fact that he says $H_A(\mathbb Z)$ *is* the underlying set of $A$.

Comment: @user634426 I believe so.

Comment: In set theory we use "is" to denote strict equality (so two sets are the same "if they have the same exact elements"), while in category theory "is" means it is isomorphic..

Comment: @panoulis But a line below Leinster says that $A$ and $A'$ have "isomorphic" underlying sets, so he does use "isomorphic underlying sets" instead of "same underlying sets" or something like that. Anyway, it's clear what he means now.

Comment: @panoulis $U_p$ maps $G$ to the set of elements of order $1$ or $p$ (not to the number of elements of prime order). And the image is not the same as the set of elements of order exactly $p$ (which Example 4.3.11 is talking about), is it?

Comment: You are right I edited my answer.. So $U_p$ is forgetful, do you know what a forgetful functor is (if you do, that will help you understand what happens)? Now there is only one element in every group of order 1 (namely 1) and therefore if $|U_p(G_1)|=|U_p(G_2)|$ then $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same number of elements of order 1 or order p, so they have the same number of elements of order $p$ (since the number of elements of order p is $|U_p(G)|-1$)

Comment: @user634426 I would say that saying "$H_A(\mathbb Z)$ *is* $A$" means that they are *canonically* isomorphic (aka naturally isomorphic). On the other hand, the assumption is that $H_A(B)$ and $H_{A'}(B)$ are not necessarily canonically isomorphic but rather you have to choose an isomorphism. For instance in linear algebra (finite dimensional) we could say that $V^{**}$ is just $V$ because $V$ is canonically isomorphic to its double dual but we would never (or should never) say that $V^*$ is $V$ because that isomorphism depends on a choice of basis.